# React native for android

Tags: react-native

Can I use react native as a backend in Android 
I want to use all the UI components from Android only but for the logic part I want to call react native and do the backend there 
Is it possible ?

Comment: The logic part could be fully in the front, depending on what you're planning to do... But you can't put React code on the server, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: No I don't want the react code on server , it will be in the app only but instead of doing backend in Java , I want to call js file of react native , can we do it

Answer (score 1):

Let me summarize your question to see if I got it right: You would like to use Native UI Components in Android and compose/utilize them using React Native.

If so the answer is yes. React Native does nothing else under the hood, they try to map as directly as possible to the native UI concepts. If this is still too much JS UI layer for you, you can directly implement the Native UI Components you need and bridge them into React Native, as to be seen [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html).

Answer (score 0):

As React native is doing for us to convert   and other component in native android component. If you don't want to use this react native component code then you have to create native android module in react native to use native component. But it's not advisable.